# Using preserveAspectRatio for external svg

Tags: html, css, image, svg

```css
#c{
    height: 160px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
    <img src="https://restcountries.eu/data/caf.svg" alt="" preserveAspectRatio="none">
</div>
```

In the above snippet, I want my image to stretch the dimensions of the container without cutting. I don't mind if the image loses its aspect ratio.

If I use a png image instead of a svg, the image stretches according to my need. But while using an svg, the image preserves its aspect ratio.

I found that if I have a svg, I can use `preserveAspectRatio` as below -

```css
.c{
    height: 160px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}

svg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Preserving aspect ratio - 
<div class="c">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="450" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1200 800">
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="0" x="0" fill="#003082"/>
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="200" x="0" fill="#FFF"/>
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="400" x="0" fill="#289728"/>
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="600" x="0" fill="#FFCE00"/>
    <rect height="800" width="200" y="0" x="500" fill="#D21034"/>
    <polygon fill="#FFCE00" points="0,-1,0.22451,-0.30902,0.95106,-0.30902,0.36327,0.11803,0.58779,0.80902,0,0.38197,-0.58779,0.80902,-0.36327,0.11803,-0.95106,-0.30902,-0.22451,-0.30902" transform="translate(200,108.59425) scale(90)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<br>
Not preserving aspect ratio (What I want) - 
<div class="c">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="450" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="0" x="0" fill="#003082"/>
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="200" x="0" fill="#FFF"/>
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="400" x="0" fill="#289728"/>
    <rect height="200" width="1200" y="600" x="0" fill="#FFCE00"/>
    <rect height="800" width="200" y="0" x="500" fill="#D21034"/>
    <polygon fill="#FFCE00" points="0,-1,0.22451,-0.30902,0.95106,-0.30902,0.36327,0.11803,0.58779,0.80902,0,0.38197,-0.58779,0.80902,-0.36327,0.11803,-0.95106,-0.30902,-0.22451,-0.30902" transform="translate(200,108.59425) scale(90)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

But since I am fetching the svg from an external site, I cannot alter the `svg` tag.

Any solutions to this issue?

Comment: Use `object-fit: fill`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @Terry `object-fit: fill` works with png but not with svg.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an [SVG fragment identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) to override the value of preserveAspectRatio e.g.

```css
#c{
    height: 160px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
    <img src="https://restcountries.eu/data/caf.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))">
</div>
```