# Img not stretching to meet desired aspect ratio

Tags: css

The svg flags from flagcdn have varying aspect ratios, and I'm trying to force them all into a 3/2 aspect ratio, but with the 2 approaches I've tried below the Brazil flag shows some white space on the sides while the GB flag above and below. How I can fix it?

```css
li {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.inline-flag {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.9em;
  transform: translate(0, 0.15em);
  border: black 2px solid;
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
}

div img {
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>without div</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img class="inline-flag" src="https://flagcdn.com/fr.svg"> France
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="inline-flag" src="https://flagcdn.com/br.svg"> Brazil
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="inline-flag" src="https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg"> Great Britain
  </li>
</ul>

<h1>with div</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="inline-flag"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/fr.svg"></div> France
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inline-flag"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/br.svg"></div> Brazil
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inline-flag"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg"></div> Great Britain
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you saying that some distortion of the flags is OK? This may not be acceptable; for example, a circle could become an oval. However, without distortion I do not see how you can show a whole flag in a space with a differing aspect ratio if no blank margins are to appear. Baically I'm saying: it can't be done.

Comment: More on flags and aspect ratios here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aspect_ratios_of_national_flags Different countries have set different rules for their flags.

Comment: Yes, I want to stretch the images to a 3/2 aspect ratio so I'm okay with some distortion. I mostly want to use them as small icons inlined with text so it shouldn't be very noticeable. Originally I intended to use flag emojis but windows doesn't support them unfortunately.

Comment: I understand you may be OK with some distortion - I'm not so sure citizens of the various countries would be but that's an opinion, not allowed on SO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the aspect ratio of the SVG using the fragment identifier `#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))` when loading it, e.g.

```
https://flagcdn.com/br.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))
```

More information about fragment identifiers can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG

**Working example**

```css
li {
    font-size:xx-large;
}

.inline-flag {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  border: black 2px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inline-flag > img {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="inline-flag">
            <img src="https://flagcdn.com/fr.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))">
        </div>
        France
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="inline-flag">
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/br.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))">
        </div>
        Brazil
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="inline-flag">
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))">
        </div>
        Great Britain
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice solution, I wasn't aware you could pass a parameter like that in a url. What's that syntax called? Is there a doc somewhere so I can read more about it? Or is it something specific to flagcdn?

Comment: I've added a link to the official documentation.

Comment: I wasn't aware either. I've dug it out from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers) via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67677111/12571484) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your flags don't resize is because they're SVGs and they don't resize unless the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute within the SVG itself is set to `none`. If you look at the SVG source you'll see this isn't set. If you copy/paste the SVG yourself then change that attribute you can get it to work. See code below:

```css
li {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

li > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.9em;
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

li > div > :is(img, svg) {
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  transform: translateY(-1px); /*nudge up a bit */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 30" width="1200" height="600" preserveAspectRatio="none"><clipPath id="a"><path d="M0 0v30h60V0z"/></clipPath><clipPath id="b"><path d="M30 15h30v15zv15H0zH0V0zV0h30z"/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#a)"><path d="M0 0v30h60V0z" fill="#012169"/><path d="M0 0l60 30m0-30L0 30" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="6"/><path d="M0 0l60 30m0-30L0 30" clip-path="url(#b)" stroke="#C8102E" stroke-width="4"/><path d="M30 0v30M0 15h60" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="10"/><path d="M30 0v30M0 15h60" stroke="#C8102E" stroke-width="6"/></g></svg></div> Great Britain
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `object-fit: cover;` in with `div`

```css
li {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.inline-flag {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.9em;
  transform: translate(0, 0.15em);
  border: black 2px solid;
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
}

div img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>without div</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img class="inline-flag" src="https://flagcdn.com/fr.svg"> France
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="inline-flag" src="https://flagcdn.com/br.svg"> Brazil
  </li>
  <li>
    <img class="inline-flag" src="https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg"> Great Britain
  </li>
</ul>

<h1>with div and object-fit: cover</h1>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="inline-flag"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/fr.svg"></div> France
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inline-flag"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/br.svg"></div> Brazil
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="inline-flag"><img src="https://flagcdn.com/gb.svg"></div> Great Britain
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `cover` mantains the image's original aspect ratio, which is not what I'm trying to do. For these flags it looks alright but for a different image that has some kind of detail near the borders using `cover` might make that part of the image dissapear